# Java Hibernate Memory leak

Tags: java, apache-flex, hibernate, memory-leaks, blazeds

I'm developing a Flex application with BlazeDS and I'm experiencing memory leak when using java to query from MySQL in hibernate. Can anyone tell me how to deal with this memory leak? It seems that each time query is invoke java.exe takes more memory.

Thanks

Sample of my java

```
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

Query find = em.createNamedQuery("Plan.findByStudentId");
find.setParameter("studentId", studentID);

List<Plan> c = find.getResultList();

return c;
```

Comment: How do you diagnostic it's a memory leak ? What is called a memory leak is when your application retains object that are not needed anymore, you see it if after every garbage collection you have less memory free than after the previous garbage collection... till you get an OutOfMemoryError...

Comment: oh, you are using glassfish. Check my update answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are leaving your `EntityManager` open after you return the data to flex, which in turn means that your MySQL Connection remains open. That's where the memory leak most likely comes from. So - close your `EntityManager`.

In anoter comment you said that you are using GlassFish. That's a whole new scenario. Is your class this a Servlet? An EJB?. GlassFish is supposed to manage your EntityManagers (if the class itself is managed), so you don't have to create or close it yourself. In such cases use `@PersistenceContext` annotation to inject the `EntityManager` (instead of using `Persistence.create..`)

But the thing you must do whatever the setup, is to start a profiler and see where is this memory allocated.

Comment: Tried it but still doesn't work. I put em.close(); at one line before every return but the memory still grows unreasonably.

Comment: did it close successfully?
Have in mind that the memory could grow to some point until garbage-collected, so, as noted in the comment on your question, wait to see if an OutOfMemoryError would occur.

Comment: Can you give me a full example of how things should look like? 

currently, I just added

em.clear();
                    em.close();
                    factory.close();

before return and it seems to help more or less. Is this correct?

Comment: if it works for you, then OK. But tell me what is this class? Is it simply a POJO, which is loaded by BlazeDS? Or is it a servlet/EJB? In the former case perhaps the manual handling is appropriate. In the latter - I'll give you some links.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just need to out your code in a try catch block and close the entity manager.

```
try{
    if(em !=null){
        em.close();
    }
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    em.close();
}
```

Comment: Now I got java.lang.IllegalStateException : EntityManager is closed

I'm using Glassfish v3 by the way. Is there anything to do with this?